# Hadoop passing variables to mapper and reducer

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm a complete beginner with Hadoop.  I've built Word Count, and I'm fairly sure I understand the basics, but I'm having trouble extending that to an actual problem.  My (modified) code is below:

```
for (Item i : set) {
    for (Item j : set) {
        Score s = score(i, j);
        renderer.render(s);
    }
}
```

I'd like to use Hadoop to distribute this.  I can write a Mapper and a Reducer, but I don't know how to pass the set to the Mapper and the renderer to the Reducer (or if that's even the idiomatic way to handle this).  I also feel like I need to write my own Writable to handle passing the pair (i, j) between the Mapper and Reducer, but I don't know the best way to do this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is essentially a cartesian product of `set` with itself.
You would probably need to implement a custom input format.

Here is an example of a generic Cartesian Product job: https://github.com/adamjshook/mapreducepatterns/blob/master/MRDP/src/main/java/mrdp/ch5/CartesianProduct.java

You can see the same logic you have done above to the input paths at line 67-77: https://github.com/adamjshook/mapreducepatterns/blob/master/MRDP/src/main/java/mrdp/ch5/CartesianProduct.java#L67-L77